# correct sequence of including .js files for client side mvc validation

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

these .js files i included in my .aspx

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../Scripts/Plugins/jqGrid/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/Plugins/JqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../../Content/Css/JqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

i am getting error 
"invlid label" in jquery.. min.js

is there any correct sequence in which files are included. 
please let me know if am wrong somewhere ....

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to include jquery.min.js before including it's plugins. Because plugins uses jquery and invalid label is not due to the order of including.

Comment: if i do not include the jquery.validate.js then there will not be any error but my client side validations are not working but when i include it i get invalid lable error.